# Is it okay to make API requests to set up tests in Cypress when testing serverless applications?

Tags: e2e-testing, serverless, cypress, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I'm writing a serverless React app using AWS Amplify. I do my E2E tests using Cypress.

Before each test, I log the user in via the AWS Amplify CLI. Afterwards, I clear all data on the development server and create some new data using fixtures. This way I always have controlled state for each test (see code below).

My question is: Is this a good practice? Or is it bad to make that many requests against the server in before each test? If it is bad, how would you do that if you do not have direct access to the server (again serverless) to run commands like `cy.exec('npm run db:reset && npm run db:seed')`? Cypress does warn me in the console about the use of promises:

```
Cypress detected that you returned a promise in a test, but also invoked one or more cy commands inside of that promise.
```

Here is the code I use:

```
import API, { graphqlOperation } from '@aws-amplify/api';
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import * as R from 'ramda';

import config from '../../src/aws-exports';
import { contacts } from '../../src/contacts/fixtures';
import { replaceEmptyStringsWithNull } from '../../src/contacts/helpers';
import {
  createContact as addMutation,
  deleteContact as deleteMutation
} from '../../src/graphql/mutations';
import { listContacts } from '../../src/graphql/queries';

Amplify.configure(config);

const deleteContact = input =>
  API.graphql(graphqlOperation(deleteMutation, { input }));

const createContact = input =>
  API.graphql(graphqlOperation(addMutation, { input }));

describe('Contactlist', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await Auth.signIn(Cypress.env('email'), Cypress.env('password'));
    const allContacts = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listContacts));
    await Promise.all(
      R.map(
        R.pipe(
          R.prop('id'),
          id => ({ id }),
          deleteContact
        )
      )(allContacts.data.listContacts.items)
    );
    await Promise.all(
      R.map(
        R.pipe(
          R.dissoc('id'),
          replaceEmptyStringsWithNull,
          createContact
        )
      )(contacts)
    );
  });

  // ... my tests
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be exactly the way I would perform the test. I love to start with a fully controlled state, even if that means having multiple API-calls as a before()